# Package Maven With Profile

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I am running spring boot, and I have a spring boot with 3 profiles. They are as follows.

```
applicaton.properties
{Empty file}

application-local.properties
test.variable = '1'

application-server.properties
test.variable = '2'
```

Now, when I run my springboot, I have one or the other profiles always running, depending on if its my server or local env. I have an `@value` to parse these values. However, when I run `mvn package`, it freaks out, since it does not pick a profile to package, and when compiling and trying to compile the `@value` line it cannot find `test.variable`, since it does not exist on `applicaton.properties`. How do I `mvn package` to compile this to a jar?

Also, I understand that when running this application, all I need to do is add `-Dspring.profiles.active={profile}`, but say I compile under the `local` profile, can I still run the jar under the `server` profile properly later?

Thanks!

A bit more of an update... I am attempting to run this command: `mvn package -P local`

Maven throws this exception:

```
    {bunch of other stacktrace stuff}
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'test.variable' in value "${test.variable}"
```

Please note that when I run this application in intellij, and in my run configurations, when I select to run 'local' as my profile, it works perfectly, so its just a matter of getting maven to use the local profile properly.

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) --- "*... say I compile under the `local` profile, can I still run the jar under the `server` profile properly later?*" - Yes. Only case that I know of where profiles matter at compile-time (from quarkus) is native compilation.

Comment: @Turing85 Thanks for the feedback! I will keep this in my in future posts! Still looking for an answer for my 1st question though! Love your response to my 2nd part! :)

Comment: You are confusing spring profiles, which have effects when you run your spring application, and maven profiles, which have an effect when you run maven. They are unrelated.

Comment: You haven't shown enough of your maven output for us to answer your question.

Comment: @tgdavies understood. but in this particular case, how do I compile with maven? maven will not let me compile, because it cannot find the correct spring profile to satisfy value annotation

Comment: Also, the error is : [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project backendDB: There are test failures

Comment: You have tests which want to run your application. You'll need to run them with a Spring profile which works (your default profile doesn't)

Comment: There are annotation for spring boot tests @Profile("production") etc. (Take a look into spring boot doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles) ...

Answer (score 1):

Spring profile is just a parameter for your application that is used by spring framework to set up different beans/properties and hence define different application behaviour. Also spring profile is runtime parameter and used only during the running the application. There is no relation between maven profile and spring profile.

So when you wrote

> when I run mvn package, it freaks out, since it does not pick a profile to package, and when compiling and trying to compile the @value line it cannot find test.variable, since it does not exist on applicaton.properties. How do I mvn package to compile this to a jar?

it does not make much sence - because

1. `maven` does not know aboout spring profiles.
2. `maven` does not use (and should not use) `spring profile` for compiling/packaging your application since `spring profile` is it runtime parameter.

> How do I mvn package to compile this to a jar?

To package your spring boot application to jar one can use spring-boot-maven-plugin. The easiest way to start is to use https://start.spring.io/, which prepate initial maven project sceleton for you.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple options to solve this:

- Provide a default value for your variable

```java
@Value("${test.variable:my-default-value}")
String variable;
```

- Set profile via maven for tests

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
     ...
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <argLine>-Dspring.profiles.active=local</argLine>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

- Provide test variable via src/**test**/resources/application.properties

```
# application.properties in test/resources folder
test.variable = test
```

...